# Transform example from PIXIJS to Expo-PIXI

Tags: react-native, expo, pixi.js

I'm having a hard time transforming PixiJS example to Expo-Pixi

**ENV**

```
"expo": "~38.0.8",
"expo-asset": "~8.1.7",
"expo-pixi": "^1.2.0",
"expo-gl": "^8.4.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
```

**Source Eample**
https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-advanced/scratchcard.js

**Progress**

I Tried Expo-Pixi very basic [example](https://github.com/expo/expo-pixi), and all I got is a Black Screen

**Challenges**

1. Loading image from assets as *Background*
2. Loading image from URI as *ImageToReveal*
3. Render anything other than **Black Screen of Desperation**

Any help, sources, tutorials, samples,...anything is more than welcomed!

Comment: That expo-pixi project has old pixi.js version 4.7.0 in dependencies - when latest version is 5.3.3 ( https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/releases ). Maybe that is a problem (incompatiblity somewhere) ?

Comment: FWIW I'm open to using any other package too. i tried expo-phaser, but it seems like it lacks support for Expo ~38.x.x